# List<Color> returning null when fetching from Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm attempting to generate a gradient for a user profile on this app I'm making and to achieve this, I set up the user model to hold two unique colors generated randomly by Dart Math. However, when I try to query the colors (this works) and instantiate a new list of type color, the list is empty.

The colors are stored as Strings in the Firestore database. An example of this is posted below:
[Firestore screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTZ1T.png)

Here's my code for fetching those color strings:

```
getColors() async {
    final firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final currentUserUid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;

    DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
        await firebaseFirestore.collection('users').doc(currentUserUid).get();
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    userColorOne = Color(int.parse(data['user_color_one'].toString()));
    userColorTwo = Color(int.parse(data['user_color_two'].toString()));

    newList.add(userColorOne);
    newList.add(userColorTwo);
}
```

userColorOne and userColorTwo are set to white by default. The newList is of type Color (`List<Color> newList = List.empty(growable = true`)).

The function I use to return the list is:

```
List<Color> returnList() {
    return newList;
}
```

However, when I pass the list into the BoxDecoration widget for the gradient, an error pops up in the debug console saying that there needs to be at least two colors in the list for a gradient to be made. That means either the colors are null (which they aren't) or the list is. I don't really know if parsing the String value from Firestore is the correct way to get the numerical color value either so there could be an issue stemming from there. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Where are you calling getColors()?